# What is this icon on the status bar that looks like a cracked egg? (see screenshot)

Tags: notification-icons

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note 5 on Android Marshmallow. I was just wondering what that oval-shaped symbol near the top center was.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not sure which app/message it belongs to, but it must come from some system app (as it appears on the right side, it's a system (status) notification). Can you check your *QuickSettings* if they contain something similar looking which is activated? The Android version on your device might be helpful to know, too.

Comment: Can you provide us the output of `adb shell dumpsys statusbar`? You would need [tag:adb] setup in PC and [tag:usb-debugging] enabled in device. Can you also select SystemUI in [Resource Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aaron.resourcebrowser) app and see if that icon shows up there?

Answer (score 2):

According to [a mod to remove the icon on XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tmobile-galaxy-note5/themes-apps/mod-remove-rcs-service-volte-icon-t3362336), it's **RCS Service**.

According to [GSM Association (GSMA)](http://www.gsma.com/network2020/technology/rcs/), the one behind the development of RCS technology,

> **What is RCS?**
>
> Rich Communications Services (RCS) is the platform that enables delivery of communication experiences beyond voice and SMS. It provides consumers with instant messaging or chat, one to one or to groups, live video and file sharing across devices on any network.
>
> RCS marks the transition of messaging and voice capabilities from Circuit Switched technology to an all-IP world. It shares the same IMS investment and leverages the same IMS capabilities as VoLTE and video calls over LTE.